# SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
def RandomString (length,distribution):
    string = ""
    for t in distribution:
        ((t[1])/length) * t[1] += string
    return shuffle (string)
```

This returns a syntax error as described in the title. In this example, `distribution` is a list of tuples, with each tuple containing a letter, and its distribution, with all the distributions from the list adding up to 100, for example:

```
[("a",50),("b",20),("c",30)]
```

And `length` is the length of the string that you want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Python is upset because you are attempting to assign a value to something that can't be assigned a value.

```
((t[1])/length) * t[1] += string
```

When you use an assignment operator, you assign the value of what is on the right to the variable or element on the left.  In your case, there is no variable or element on the left, but instead an interpreted value: you are trying to assign a value to something that isn't a "container".

Based on what you've written, you're just misunderstanding how this operator works.  Just switch your operands, like so.

```
string += str(((t[1])/length) * t[1])
```

Note that I've wrapped the assigned value in `str` in order to convert it into a `str` so that it is compatible with the `string` variable it is being assigned to.  (Numbers and strings can't be added together.)

Comment: That gives me a type error TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
Any ideas?

Comment: Yes.  But it all depends on what you want `string` to look like.  Please elaborate on what the value of `string` should be based on the example input you provided.  I've amended my answer with a guess as to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 54):

Make sure the variable does not have a hyphen (-).

Hyphens are not allowed in variable names in Python and are used as subtraction operators.

Example:

```
my-variable = 5   # would result in 'SyntaxError: can't assign to operator'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `((t[1])/length) * t[1] += string`, you should use `string  += ((t[1])/length) * t[1]`.  (The other syntax issue  - `int is not iterable` - will be your exercise to figure out.)

Comment: I just tried that and its telling me TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

Comment: HINT:  You can't use `distribution` in that sense in Python's `for` statement.  Perhaps a `range` of your distribution would be suitable...?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the error says, you have an expression (`((t[1])/length) * t[1]`) on the left side of the assignment, rather than a variable name. You have that expression, and then you tell Python to add `string` to it (which is always `""`) and assign it to... where? `((t[1])/length) * t[1]` isn't a variable name, so you can't store the result into it.

Did you mean `string += ((t[1])/length) * t[1]`? That would make more sense. Of course, you're still trying to add a number to a string, or multiply by a string... one of those `t[1]`s should probably be a `t[0]`.

Comment: Yes it should t[0], my code isn't normally this full of errors, ive just retyped it about 10 times trying to figure this our..

Answer (score -2):

What do you think this is supposed to be: `((t[1])/length) * t[1] += string`

Python can't parse this, it's a syntax error.

Comment: Well actually its meant to be this, I just relised ((t[1]/10)/length) * t[1] Basically its taking the destribution for each letter, figuring out how many times that letter needs to be in random string that its making, and then adding that many letters to the empty string, named string

Comment: @user1048244: It's not relevant what it's for - as written it's not syntactically valid.

Answer (score -8):

in python only work

```
a=4
b=3
```

---

```
i=a+b
```

which i is new operator