# Concatenate counter to variable name in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
for i in range(1,8):
    worksheet+i = gSheet.wks.get_worksheet(i)
    presentations = getActivity(query, getDate(i))
    exportToSheet(query, worksheet+i, presentations)
```

I need the counter to be concatenated with the work worksheet to form a new variable name every time it loops.

Currently giving me this error:

```
  File "dagklapper.py", line 99
  worksheet+i = gSheet.wks.get_worksheet(i)
  SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: Can't you use an array?

Comment: Can't you use a dictionary?

Comment: related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have shown doesn't seem to need variables `worksheet1` to `worksheet8` at all, you could just reuse `worksheet`.

```
for i in range(1, 8):
    worksheet = gSheet.wks.get_worksheet(i)
    presentations = getActivity(query, getDate(i))
    exportToSheet(query, worksheet, presentations)
```

If you need to access the worksheets later in your code, you could create a dictionary `worksheets`. Then you could access the worksheets with `worksheets[1]`, `worksheets[2]` and so on.

```
worksheets = {}
for i in range(1, 8):
    worksheets[i] = gSheet.wks.get_worksheet(i)
    presentations = getActivity(query, getDate(i))
    exportToSheet(query, worksheets[i], presentations)
```

Comment: In your first solution, last line, delete the  `+i`

Comment: I like your solution, thank you.
Although it gives me this now: TypeError: 'Worksheet' object does not support indexing

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the traceback, I can't tell the problem from that error message alone.

Answer (score 1):

at this:- `worksheet+i = gSheet.wks.get_worksheet(i)`

When you use an assignment operator, you assign the value of what is on the right to the variable or element on the left. In your case, there is no variable or element on the left, but instead an interpreted value: you are trying to assign a value to something that isn't a "container".

from here
[syntax-error: can't assign to operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956825/cant-assign-to-operator-error-i-dont-understand)