# Concatenate variable to variable

Tags: python

Python noob here so forgive me if I have an easy question. I want to set the variable name to whatever value I am passing using my for loop.

```
roles = ["A" , "B" , "C"]
for role in roles:
    print (role)
    "outPutFor"+role = function_that_gives_outputforRole(role)
```

So I want my variables to read `outPutForA` , `outPutForB` and `outPutForC` .

but I am getting the below ERROR

```
    "outPutFor"+role = function_that_gives_outputforRole(role)
           ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: The error indicates the issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956825/syntax-error-cant-assign-to-operator.

Comment: You probably don't want to do that, presumably it's just better to have a dictionary `outPutFor` and use `outPutFor["A"]` as you would `outPutForA`. That way you can also iterate over all possibilities easily etc.

Comment: You can not 'compute' the *name* of a variable. You can only compute the 'content' of a variable. That's why you should generalize the logic in your loop. `outPutForA` is the 'output' in the first iteration (when `role` is set to `'A'`). Hence, you might want to set `output = 'outPutFor' + role` or `output = 'outPutFor' + function_that_gives_outputforRole(role)`.

Comment: If you're really looking to dynamically create variables in your namespace, you can use `exec`, but I think the dictionary structures proposed below are much safer.

Comment: @098799 Thanks. So if I want to get the value of this variable outside of the for loop, I could be able to do `print(outPutFor["A"])` ?

Comment: @JasonStanley Yes, this would print the value. You can do anything to this `outPutFor["A"]` object that you would to the variable `outPutForA` that you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't create a dynamically named variables. But you could use a python `dict` like

```
roles = ["A" , "B" , "C"]
outputs = {}
for role in roles:
    print (role)
    outputs["outPutFor"+role] = function_that_gives_outputforRole(role)
```

or create a `dict` with elements from 'roles' list as keys. Like

```
roles = ["A" , "B" , "C"]
outPutFor = {}
for role in roles:
    print (role)
    outPutFor[role] = function_that_gives_outputforRole(role)
    print(outPutFor[role])
```

Comment: Why would you use `outputs.update({key: value})` instead of the normal `outputs[key] = value` ?

Comment: @khelwood Thank you for comment. Yes, `outputs[key] = value` is better solution. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to store the `output` of each iteration of this function, you can create a `list` called `results`, for example, and `for each role in roles`, you can `insert/assign` the output of `function_that_gives_outputforRole` into the `results` list.

**Example:**

```
roles = ["A" , "B" , "C"]
results = []
for i, role in enumerate(roles):
    results[i] = function_that_gives_outputforRole(role)
```

In this example, you can access the output value for each role like this:

```
results[0] = function_that_gives_outputforRole("A")
results[1] = function_that_gives_outputforRole("B")
results[2] = function_that_gives_outputforRole("C")
```

You can also use a `dict` structure to store each output, as stated in [kvorobiev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43499127/3846228).

If you want, you can `zip()` these two lists into a single list to consolidate the input/output values.