# Reading in multiple files in Python and renaming them using string - str(i+1) not working?

Tags: python, string, loops

I have the following loop, where `cfile` has been defined as `'C_'` previously.

```
for i in range(15,25):
    infile = cfile + str(i+1) + '.txt'
    C + str(i+1) = np.loadtxt(infile, delimiter=',')
```

I have many files in the working directory named `C_1`, `C_2`, etc.

I'd like to import these files into Python and name them as `C_1`, `C_2`, etc, but I'd only like to do so for that certain range. I am not understanding why the `str(i+1)` will not work.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) and [SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8956825/4518341)

Comment: BTW, "not working" is generally not helpful. For debugging, we need to know *exactly* what error you're getting, preferably with the full traceback. See [mre] for reference, and [ask] if you want other tips.

Comment: I would recommend you use dictionaries or append these files to a list named `C` then each variable will be `C[0]` instead of `C_0` and you'll be able to do some logic based on the numbers too

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to open all files with a specified pattern. Although it's patterns follow Unix guidelines and may need to be further filtered to meet your specifications:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob("C_[1-2][1-9].txt")
```

Or just load all the correct files into a dict as it's the recommended way of creating a variable amount of variables.

```
files = {f"C{i}": np.loadtxt(f"{cfile}{i}.txt", delimiter=',') for i in range(16,26)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cfile='C_'
C='What_'
H={}
for i in range(15,25):
    infile = cfile + str(i+1) + '.txt'
    #print("infile:",infile)
    k=C+str(i+1)
    H[k] = np.loadtxt(infile, delimiter=',')
    print(f"Your loaded file is here: H[{k}]")

    #PRINT OUT THE CONTENT OF THE FILE 
    print(H[k])
```

just use `print(H[k])` to print out the content of each file. Or `print( H["What_24"] )`, or if you change the string of variable C = 'C_' then you can `print(H["C_24"] )` and view the content of file stored inside the `dict`.

**Why what you wanted to do was an error:**

```
C + str(i+1) = np.loadtxt(infile, delimiter=',')
```

Because  `C` is undefined ...  and if it were defined like `C='What_you_want'` you would have gotten:

```
'What_you_want'+str(i+1)  ->   'What_you_want'+'number' -> 'What_you_wantnumber'
```

So

`'What_you_wantnumber'` is a string  which resides inside the `variable C`

`np.loadtxt(infile, delimiter=',')` is a method that return the content o the file as a string .

so you can't  assign  string = string .  But you can  do

`variable = string`

for example:   the variable `name = "flagello"` ok

```
 print(name)
```

output :  flagello    #that is  as string

```
"flagello"="flagello"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

```
"flagello"="silicio"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

```
'flagello' == 'silico'
```

Output: False

```
'flagello' == 'flagello'
```

Output: True

```
You can compare strings  but you can t assing a string to a string .

You can assign a string value  to a variable.
```

But at this moment nothing rename nothing .  Now you get the content of the files ,  assign the content of each file  inside a **dict**  ad print the content of the **dict**

**How to rename a file**

```
import os
os.rename(r'C_21.txt',r'CCCP_21.txt')
```

In this case you don't need to read the content of the file to rename it.

Just  use the `old name`  and  the `new name`

Comment: This worked, but I am not understanding why I cannot use print(C_24) to pull up the file. I continue to get the 
NameError: name is not defined, which I thought the loop should have taken care of.

Comment: See  edited answer:    just use  print(H[k])  to print out the content of each  file. 
Or  print(H["What_24"] ), or  if you change the string of  variable C = 'C_'   then you can print(H["C_24"] )

Comment: I hope I have clarified your doubts